# SQL Server Replace Censored Words In a Select From Replace Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have two tables:

***Word_Blacklist***

```
  | Black_Word | Replace_Word
1 | foo        | f**
2 | bar        | b**
```

and ***ESCodes***

```
  | Beircht
1 | this bar has good food
2 | foo foo sentences
```

When selecting Bericht from ESCodes I want to **replace all occurrences of a substring *Black_Word* with *Replace_Word*** such that my results look like:

```
this b** has good f**d
f** f** sentences
```

How can I do this?

Comment: No need to use offensive words as examples

Comment: Does [Bericht] contain only one word and we can join this field on the "black listed" words or does [Bericht] contain many words and each occasion of any "black listed" word should be eliminated (which would require a recursive loop for all black listed words)?

Comment: it can hold more words,,

Comment: @Ferrybig Only reply if you have something usefull to say.

i'm showing words that has to be replaced and in this case they are offensive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: You can do this with a dynamic replace. This was suggested as an answer to a different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220267/tsql-replace-same-field-multiple-times-in-one-query).

```
-- first generate the replace statement with all Black_Words
declare @replace varchar(max)
select @replace = coalesce ('replace(' + @replace,'replace(bericht') + ',''' + Black_Word + ''',''' + Replace_Word + ''')'
FROM Word_Blacklist

-- execute statement
exec( 'select ' + @replace + 'from ESCodes')
```

Comment: to complicated and doesn't work


It has to be done in a SELECT   

i don't need to update

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
select IIF(exists(select name from table2), '****', name)
from table1
```

Comment: right idea but the exists is missing a where clause

Comment: @FuzzyTree, we don't need where clause for exists, because if a name exists in table2, it is black-listed.

Comment: without a where the subquery will always return the same thing for every row (either table2 is empty or not). that doesn't seem useful. i understood the solution as `select IIF(exists(select 1 from table2 where table2.name = table1.name), '****', name)
from table1`

Comment: @FuzzyTree, table2 is a pool of bad words and if table1.name is in that pool we want to replace it with *****, Sorry I don't get what you mean

Answer (score 0):

If you need a high performance solution, it's can be easily done using Eval SQL.NET

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Eval SQL.NET](http://eval-sql.net/)

The library let you use C# syntax directly in SQL.

```
DECLARE @tableMessage TABLE ( Msg VARCHAR(250) )

DECLARE @tableReplace TABLE
    (
      Original_Word VARCHAR(50) ,
      Replace_Word VARCHAR(50)
    )

INSERT  INTO @tableMessage
        ( Msg )
VALUES  ( 'A test to replace FromWord1 and FromWord2!' ),
        ( 'FromWord1FromWord1FromWord1 FromWord1 FromWord2' )


INSERT  INTO @tableReplace
        ( Original_Word, Replace_Word )
VALUES  ( 'FromWord1', 'ToWord1' ),
        ( 'FromWord2', 'ToWord2' )


DECLARE @sqlnet SQLNET = SQLNET::New('')
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = 'template'
DECLARE @pos VARCHAR(10) = '0';

-- CREATE the sql and set parameter value
SELECT  @sql = @sql + '.Replace(old_' + @pos + ', new_' + @pos + ')' ,
        @sqlnet = @sqlnet.ValueString('old_' + @pos, Original_Word)
                         .ValueString('new_' + @pos, Replace_Word) ,
        @pos = CAST(@pos AS INT) + 1
FROM    @tableReplace

-- SET the code to evaluate
-- template.Replace(old_0, new_0).Replace(old_1, new_1)
SET @sqlnet = @sqlnet.Code(@sql).Root();

-- Evaluate the code
SELECT  Msg ,
        @sqlnet.ValueString('template', Msg).EvalString()
FROM    @tableMessage AS A
```

Comment: this is too big and too complex i had my answer and it's much more easyer than this